# integral over a bounded domain of a bounded (from below) function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded domain and $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous and bounded from below function.

It is true that a positive constant $C$ exists such that
$$\int_{\Omega} f(t) dt\geq C?$$
I think it is true, but how to prove it?

Could anyone please help?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What about $\int_0^1 \left(t^2- t\right) \, dt$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider $f(x)=0$ on $x\in(0,1)$.

If you have a negative lower bound, cancellation could happen.

But if you have $f\ge 0$ (and continuous), then $\int_\Omega f>0$ if $f$ is not constantly zero.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In my hypotheses, may I say, at least, that $\int_{\Omega} f(t) dt \geq -C$?

Comment: @C.Bishop: that's right by $\int_\Omega f\ge \int_\Omega g$ if $f\ge g$ on $\Omega$.